# How to insert same records from one table to another table 4 to 5 times randomly

Tags: sql

**table 1** is my current table. **newtable** is what needs to be insert into.

Here's the example:
**Table 1**

```
a
b
c
d
```

**newTable**

```
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
b
b
c
c
c
c
c
d
d
d
d
```

Comment: So far you have an Oracle answer and a MySQL answer. You might want to tag the actual database this needs to be done in.

Comment: i have the answer. thanks! Use a random function: SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(6-4)+4). then put an insert statement in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Oracle:

```
SELECT x, LEVEL from myTable t
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (4, 5))
and prior x = x
and prior sys_guid() is not null;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using mysql;

```
select * from table order by rand() limit 3
then
Insert it into new new table
```

Do it many times as you want.

You can follow [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18943417/how-to-quickly-select-3-random-records-from-a-30k-mysql-table-with-a-where-filte)

Thank You,

Sameera

Comment: Possibly you meant `INSERT INTO newtable SELECT * FROM table ...` ?

Comment: yes, if want it more random, limit it to 1 record and insert. you can loop it for 4-5 times